# Posting tweet to twitter using STTwitter in iOS

Tags: ios, twitter, sttwitter

I am using STTwitterAPI for creating app that performs all operations of twitter .
I am receiving timeline feeds. But how to post the tweet using the same API . I searched for this however i found only SLComposeViewController to post the tweet which will present the controller then we can post tweet with location and image. 
What i am trying to do is create my own compose view . So if any one has some solution for this please do write to this thread .

Thnx and Regards,

pagyy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The full method is:

```
[twitter postStatusUpdate:@"test"
        inReplyToStatusID:nil
                 latitude:nil
                longitude:nil
                  placeID:nil
       displayCoordinates:nil
                 trimUser:nil
             successBlock:^(NSDictionary *status) {
    // ...
} errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    // ...
}];
```

Comment: thnx is there any doc which has detailed description and usage for STTwitterAPI

Comment: Twitter API is documented here https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1 all API endpoints have their Objective-C front-end in STTwitter.h https://github.com/nst/STTwitter/blob/master/STTwitter/STTwitterAPI.h